# How do you indicate sections in a report if there are more than 5? (まず、つぎに、さらに、そして、最後に)

Tags: word-choice, syntax, set-phrases, counters, academic-japanese

If you need to indicate more sections in a report than five (beginning each section with [「まず」、「つぎに」、「さらに」、「そして」、「最後に」](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14100149) respectively), what word(s) should you use to indicate the start of the additional sections?

Do you insert them after 「そして」 but before 「最後に」?

Comment: Hmm.. how about また?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no implicit order which word you should use for stacking sections. You can (basically) freely choose linking words for your additional sections.

A non-exhaustive list is:

> 次{つぎ}に, 更{さら}に（は）, そして, それから, その上{うえ}（に）, この上{うえ}（に）, 加{くわ}えて, それに加{くわ}え（て）, 他{ほか}に（も）, また, 並{なら}びに, および, それだけでなく, のみならず etc. etc.

Variations for "firstly" and "finally" are:

> まず, 初{はじ}めに, 最初{さいしょ}に, 第一{だいいち}に, etc.

and

> 終{お}わりに, 最後{さいご}に, おしまいに, etc.

Comment: Also, one of my favorites... しかも、

Comment: I got some weird responses a while ago for using 第一に , 第二に, ...  does that look especially foreign?

Comment: @virmaior Not foreign, but it's a bit unfriendly to use 第二に or above without notice. You should say, for example, "I have four reasons. First, ~. Second, ~. ..."